# Flatten JSON with Jq with array index in output

Tags: json, jq, flatten

I'm trying to create a single json output based on a nested Json:

```
{
    "Id" : "1",
    "items" : [
        {"item_name" : "shirt","value" : 10},
        {"item_name" : "dress","value" : 20},
        {"item_name" : "ice cream","value" : 30}
    ] 
}
```

My expected output would be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "item_name": "shirt",
    "value": 10,
    "index_position": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "item_name": "dress",
    "value": 20,
    "index_position": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "item_name": "ice cream",
    "value": 30,
    "index_position": 2
  }
]
```

The only output that I was able to fetch is on this snippet:

https://jqplay.org/s/G6mYAI47LE

What would be the best way to iterate over an inner array and at the same time fetch the outer object data?

Answer (score 1):

Q.E.D. as follows:

```
.Id as $Id
| .items
| [ range(0; length) as $index_position
   | {$Id} + .[$index_position] + {$index_position} ]
```

The key to brevity (or at least DRY-ness) here is that the jq expression `{$x}` expands to `{"x": $x}`.